# Show T is a linear transformation, and determine if it is 1-1 and onto

Tags: linear-algebra

I would just like confirmation of my answers.

$T: P_3(R)\rightarrow  P_3(R)$ defined by $T(f(x)) = xf''(x) + f'(x)$

I found that it is a linear transformation, but is neither 1-1 or onto. Not onto as it will obviously not contain any polynomials of degree 3 and not 1-1 as $f(x) = 1$ will be in the null space, and thus both the zero vector and $f(x) = c$ are in the nullspace.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes.  You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are right! Linear transformations are functions themselves, so what you already know about functions can be used!